# Корректность фразы

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно написать и где это определено (речь идет о вузе): «Со времен его становления до сегодняшних дней/ со времени его становления  до сегодняшних дней»?

Answer (score 1):

В предложенной фразе словосочетание "со времени его становления" представляется более уместным, так как в данном контексте понятие "время становления" имеет зачение "период становления", причем слово "время" воспринимается как целостный, непрерывный процесс, охватывающий конкретный временной отрезок. Если же употребить "времена становления", то такое словоочетание ассоциируется с различными временнЫми периодами, возможно, неравномерными, не непрерывными, состоящими из нескольких периодов. Не знаю, насколько убедительно мое пояснение, но я так чувствую. Правда, предвижу, что некоторые(-ый) из участников нашего форума вновь станет язвить по поводу "я чувствую" или "душа не лежит". Однако это его право и, если хотите,его "пунктик" критиковать все,что не соответствует его трактовкам, иногда, справедливости ради скажу, вполне разумными.

Comment: Ну если вы чувствуете даже то, что Ваши чувства будут подвергнуты критике...  То извольте. Вы опять сознательно или нет, но все переврали. Я Вас критиковал за употребление "чувств" применительно к вопросам терминологии. И наоборот, сказал, что это вполне уместно там, где ресь идет о стилистике. Так что как минимум в этом вы опять ошиблись.

По сути же ваших предложений могу сказать только одно. А Вы уверены, что замысел автора не касается "различных временнЫх периодов"? Я  - нет. У меня как раз такое ощущение, что он об этом и говорит.

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли где прописано (может, меня поправят), поскольку оба варианта вполне допустимы.
Стилистически я вижу разницу в том, что времена употребляются в отношении какого-то очень значительного исторического или протяженного события, время - во всех остальных случаях. 
Вряд ли становление вуза можно считать событие историческим, а вот протяженность по времени - это уже автор должен решить, что он имеет в виду по "становлением". Если момент, то "со времени", если это продолжалось долго и затронула разные в историческом смысле периоды - то времена вполне уместно.

Но мне очень не нравится сочетание "сегодняшний день". В единственном числе я бы еще стерпел (день сего дня = день этих суток), но "дни сего дня" - это уже откровенная абракадабра. Так что, на мой взгляд, стоит заменить на "нынешний день", в сосетании с несколько возвышенными "временами", это будет тем более оправдано.
Так что если готовящаяся речь допускает некоторую возвышенность, то ***"со времен становления до нынешнего дня"*** или "...нынешних дней".